# Camel: how to manipulate output message/set header based on xpath expression

Tags: xpath, output, apache-camel

I'm trying to dynamically create a RESTful URL based on the incoming XML:

Input:

```
<message>
   <request name="John"/>
</message>
```

I want to route it like this:

```
http://myhost:8080/myservice?name=John
```

I know how to set URL parameters using setHeader but I don't know how to extract the attribute values from the input message. The SOOPER_XPATH expression I'm looking for might look like this:

```
from("direct:start")
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,
     simple("name=$SOOPER_XPATH(${in.body}, '//request/@name')")
  .to("http://myhost:8080/myservice").log("Received response: ${in.body});
```

Comment: have you tried this XPath : `'//request/@name'`?

Comment: Indeed tThe xpath in the snippet had a typo, //request@name instead of //request/@name, sorry about that. But my problem is not with the xpath expression.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways to do it, this is what we do in one of my projects, works fine:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(XPathBuilder.xpath("/message/messageID/text()").evaluate(exchange,String.class));
```

We do this inside a processor, but you could probably use the XPathBuilder directly in a route as well.

It's really just a matter of getting the xpath right. I usually use some tool like http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath to test my xpaths.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to figure out how to use it in a route. Using  processor instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the header in the route outside of a `Processor`, use:

```
from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, xpath("//request@name").stringResult())
    .to("http://myhost:8080/myservice").log("Received response: ${in.body}");
```